# Have the submit button uncentered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a login "panel" kindof.
I just want the submit button right next to the password field but without it centering with the password field.
I have tried to uncenter the Submit button but it doesn't work.

[image]

```css
.login input:focus {
    border-color: #419ebf;
    outline-width: 0;
}
.login {
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.login .fields {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-color: #b8bfb7;
    width: 325px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: White;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.login .submit {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-color: #b8bfb7;
    font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: White;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="login.php" class="login">
    <input class="fields" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <br/>
    <input class="fields" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try using float:left; text-align:none; in .fields class. It looks like it inherits the text-align:center; from the .login class. It would be better if you could give the real page url to be able to check it directly on elements instead of an image.

Comment: I host it locally via PHPStorm so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider two things:

- If your application is always displayed on fixed width, you might like to try use `position: fixed;` instead of centering all items and using newline.
- If you'd like to be more flexible, find an anchestor or container element and use `position: absolute;`.

More information on positioning elements through CSS can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete

```
text-align: center;
```

in

```
.login{
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `text-align: center;` from `.login`, added `width: 500px;` and changed margins to `margin: 100px auto 0 auto;`

```css
.login {
    cursor: default;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
.login input:focus {
    border-color: #419ebf;
    outline-width: 0;
}
.login .fields {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-color: #b8bfb7;
    width: 325px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: White;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.login .submit {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-color: #b8bfb7;
    font-family:'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: White;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="login.php" class="login">
    <input class="fields" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <br/>
    <input class="fields" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```